# node.js/postgreSQL - Cannot set headers error despite redirect being outside async function

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, asynchronous

I'm trying to use the listingID variable in the response.redirect line outside the query function. This comes from RETURNING id from the postgreSQL query. listingID keeps coming back undefined and I get the error "[ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client". I get the same cannot set headers error if I move the response.redirect inside the query function.

Would greatly appreciate if someone can point out specifically what I have wrong and ideally provide code to fix this. I'm a newbie here - still finding my way around the concepts. Many thanks!

```
function formSubmit(request, response) {

// Start with an empty array of errors
const contextData = {
    title: 'Add listing',
    salutation: 'Please fill out the information below to post your item',
    errors: [],
};

if (request.method === 'POST') {
    const errors = [];

    if (!request.body.name || request.body.name.length > 101) {
        errors.push('Please fill out your name');
    }

    if (errors.length === 0) {

            // Add listing to listing SQL table
            var listingID;
            client.connect();
            client.query('INSERT INTO listings (name, email, school, gradyear, phone, object, price, image, firstavail, lastavail) values ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10) RETURNING id;', [request.body.name, request.body.email, request.body.school, request.body.gradyear, request.body.phone, request.body.object, request.body.price, request.body.image, request.body.firstavail, request.body.lastavail], (err, res) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                var listingID = res.rows[0].id;
                client.end();
                console.log('some listing id: ',listingID);
                cb(listingID);
                // console.log(res.rows);
            });
            response.redirect(`/listing/${listingID}`);
    }
    contextData.errors = errors;
} else {
    console.log('This is a GET request');
}
return response.render('form', contextData);
```

}

Comment: Can you post the complete code?

Comment: @SanSolo, I just edited my post to include the complete function code.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using the pg package, `pg.connect` has been deprecated. Instead you should use `Pool` as described in the official pg [documentation :](https://node-postgres.com/features/pooling).

```
   const { Pool } = require('pg')    
   const pool = new Pool()    
   pool.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $1', [1], (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
    throw err
   }    
   console.log('user:', res.rows[0])
  })
```

you can double check by doing a console log after using `client.connect`. A simple line like "successfully connected" will help.

Not sure about the cannot set headers error. But check out the documentation for [Express routing](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html). 
Using routers, you don't have to check if a method is POST or GET. instead, you simply have two different routes:

```
router.get('/register',(req,res)=>{//your code}) //this get can be used to render registration apge that has the form



 router.post('/register',(req,res)=>{//form processing code}) //this post route is used to process the data submitted through the form
```

Not only does routing makes it easier to write code, it helps in building RESTFul apis
Also, don't use `var`. Instead use `let` or `const`. 'let' variables can be reassigned, `const` cannot.